# C language evolves

Tags: c, coding-style, standards, new-operator

1) What is the newest version of C language? 2) How is GCC complying to it? 3) For an old C programmer, what is the main differences of the new language?

I'm asking this because I learned these days (a new feature) that we can actually attribute values to a struct like:

```
struct t
{
   int i;
   char c;
} s;
s = (struct t){exponent, coefficient};
```

So I'm wondering about other things I might be missing when programming...

Thanks,
Beco

Comment: [C](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/C_programming_language)

Comment: [GCC compliance](http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html) to C99 standard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most recent version of C language seems to be C99. Among the numerous changes, the most important IMHO are:

- `restrict` pointers
- variable length arrays
- built-in complex numbers
- variable declarations mixed with code
- C++-style `//` comments

[Here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/newinc9x.htm) is a bigger list.

Answer (score 4):

The last standard is [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99). I don't use this standard because GCC does not yet fully support. ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#Implementations))

There is "C1X" but it is much too premature to talk about it.

For the new features in C99, see the following post :

[What are the most useful new features in C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047065/what-are-the-most-useful-new-features-in-c99)

Answer (score 1):

The next standard is being worked on by the WG 14 group, their home page [is here](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/).  The "News 2010-12-05" link takes you to a PDF of the current draft, labeled "201x".  Paragraphs 6 and 7 highlight changes.  Googling "+gcc +c201x" gives reasonable hits, nothing much to nail to a wall.  This moves slow as a snail, C99 is not universally implemented yet either.

Comment: The ISO C standard has always clearly stated major changes from previous versions, it's right there on paragraph 6 of the Foreword.

Comment: Don't forget that Microsoft's compilers don't support C99 at all --- and apparently they have no intention of doing so. See, e.g. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/485416/support-c99, but if you look online you can find plenty of angst about this. This is a damned shame, because C99 is really nice to work with; but if you want to write portable code, it's just not an option.

Comment: Don't give a link to a page with a link, give the final link, because pages change ... as this one did.